# Is it valid to have different features in the same time series

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

In this website the authors points out the need to [`12. Standardize the features`](https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607).

However, in my case, I want to lay out different features(ie. 1) time series for the plant height; 2) times series for rainfall; 3) times series for solar exposure) in one row in a RNN model, to predict if the plant height exceeds a minimum level('healthy') or not('unhealthy'). Since the features are different, it's hard to normalise all of them to have mean 0 and std 1.

My question: is it valid to have different features(of time series format) in the same row? What are the cons and pros of doing this?

One of the training produced this output:

```
Step 1, Minibatch Loss= 1.1080, Training Accuracy= 0.539
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4765625
Step 100, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.383
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 200, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.477
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 300, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.352
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 400, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.461
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 500, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.430
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 600, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.445
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 700, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.484
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 800, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.375
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 900, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.469
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 1000, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.453
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 1100, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.359
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 1200, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.555
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 1300, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.336
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 1400, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.492
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 1500, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.461
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 1600, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.344
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 1700, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.367
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 1800, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.422
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 1900, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.359
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 2000, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.414
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 2100, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.320
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 2200, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.422
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 2300, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.391
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 2400, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.352
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 2500, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.398
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 2600, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.297
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 2700, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.336
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 2800, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.469
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 2900, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.422
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 3000, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.367
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 3100, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.438
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 3200, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.391
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 3300, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.398
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 3400, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.422
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 3500, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.445
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 3600, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.398
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 3700, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.414
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 3800, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.375
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 3900, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.398
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 4000, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.430
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 4100, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.484
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 4200, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.383
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 4300, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.398
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 4400, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.469
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 4500, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.359
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 4600, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.383
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 4700, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.336
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 4800, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.367
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 4900, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.461
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 5000, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.438
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Optimization Finished!
Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Save the model to /content/gdrive/My Drive/20191102
INFO:tensorflow:No assets to save.
INFO:tensorflow:No assets to write.
INFO:tensorflow:SavedModel written to: /content/gdrive/My Drive/20191102/model.pb
```

I suspect that it has to do with `gradient explosion` due to the very different nature of the features. Should I use `gradient clipping`? Thanks

---

Update: 
I applied Gradient Clipping to the model:

```
# Gradient Clipping
threshold = 1
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) 
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss_op) 
capped_gvs = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -threshold, threshold), var) for grad, var in grads_and_vars] 

# train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)              
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gvs)
```

The testing accuracy now no longer remains the same. However, it is really low throughout the process, something like this:

```
Step 1, Minibatch Loss= 1.8052, Training Accuracy= 0.461
-Testing Accuracy: 0.3984375
Step 100, Minibatch Loss= 1.3242, Training Accuracy= 0.398
-Testing Accuracy: 0.40625
Step 200, Minibatch Loss= 1.1659, Training Accuracy= 0.484
-Testing Accuracy: 0.3984375
Step 300, Minibatch Loss= 0.7905, Training Accuracy= 0.586
-Testing Accuracy: 0.359375
Step 400, Minibatch Loss= 1.0426, Training Accuracy= 0.516
-Testing Accuracy: 0.421875
Step 500, Minibatch Loss= 1.2217, Training Accuracy= 0.469
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4140625
Step 600, Minibatch Loss= 1.1898, Training Accuracy= 0.500
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4140625
Step 700, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.492
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5390625
Step 800, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.539
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 900, Minibatch Loss= 0.9010, Training Accuracy= 0.555
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5390625
Step 1000, Minibatch Loss= 0.8782, Training Accuracy= 0.539
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5390625
Step 1100, Minibatch Loss= 0.8861, Training Accuracy= 0.484
-Testing Accuracy: 0.6015625
Step 1200, Minibatch Loss= 0.9336, Training Accuracy= 0.492
-Testing Accuracy: 0.515625
Step 1300, Minibatch Loss= 1.0637, Training Accuracy= 0.484
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5546875
Step 1400, Minibatch Loss= 1.0548, Training Accuracy= 0.516
-Testing Accuracy: 0.578125
Step 1500, Minibatch Loss= 0.9146, Training Accuracy= 0.484
-Testing Accuracy: 0.6015625
Step 1600, Minibatch Loss= 1.0032, Training Accuracy= 0.484
-Testing Accuracy: 0.53125
Step 1700, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.539
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5625
Step 1800, Minibatch Loss= 0.9834, Training Accuracy= 0.453
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5078125
Step 1900, Minibatch Loss= 0.9774, Training Accuracy= 0.547
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5703125
Step 2000, Minibatch Loss= 0.8281, Training Accuracy= 0.602
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5390625
Step 2100, Minibatch Loss= 0.7679, Training Accuracy= 0.578
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5
Step 2200, Minibatch Loss= 0.9139, Training Accuracy= 0.539
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5234375
Step 2300, Minibatch Loss= 0.8888, Training Accuracy= 0.539
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5
Step 2400, Minibatch Loss= 0.9383, Training Accuracy= 0.500
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5859375
Step 2500, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.531
-Testing Accuracy: 0.6015625
Step 2600, Minibatch Loss= 0.9916, Training Accuracy= 0.445
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5078125
Step 2700, Minibatch Loss= 0.8760, Training Accuracy= 0.555
-Testing Accuracy: 0.625
Step 2800, Minibatch Loss= 0.8751, Training Accuracy= 0.516
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4140625
Step 2900, Minibatch Loss= 0.8013, Training Accuracy= 0.555
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4296875
Step 3000, Minibatch Loss= 0.7989, Training Accuracy= 0.617
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4453125
Step 3100, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.570
-Testing Accuracy: 0.515625
Step 3200, Minibatch Loss= 0.8795, Training Accuracy= 0.547
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4140625
Step 3300, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.547
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4921875
Step 3400, Minibatch Loss= 0.8432, Training Accuracy= 0.508
-Testing Accuracy: 0.453125
Step 3500, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.570
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4140625
Step 3600, Minibatch Loss= 0.8936, Training Accuracy= 0.555
-Testing Accuracy: 0.484375
Step 3700, Minibatch Loss= 0.8682, Training Accuracy= 0.547
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4140625
Step 3800, Minibatch Loss= 0.8836, Training Accuracy= 0.523
-Testing Accuracy: 0.421875
Step 3900, Minibatch Loss= 0.8916, Training Accuracy= 0.477
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4375
Step 4000, Minibatch Loss= 1.0473, Training Accuracy= 0.469
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4765625
Step 4100, Minibatch Loss= 0.8748, Training Accuracy= 0.531
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4453125
Step 4200, Minibatch Loss= 0.8773, Training Accuracy= 0.555
-Testing Accuracy: 0.515625
Step 4300, Minibatch Loss= 0.8434, Training Accuracy= 0.531
-Testing Accuracy: 0.4375
Step 4400, Minibatch Loss= 0.9482, Training Accuracy= 0.523
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5234375
Step 4500, Minibatch Loss= 0.7898, Training Accuracy= 0.562
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5
Step 4600, Minibatch Loss= 0.8327, Training Accuracy= 0.531
-Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
Step 4700, Minibatch Loss= 0.9477, Training Accuracy= 0.523
-Testing Accuracy: 0.375
Step 4800, Minibatch Loss= 0.9240, Training Accuracy= 0.461
-Testing Accuracy: 0.53125
Step 4900, Minibatch Loss= 1.0568, Training Accuracy= 0.484
-Testing Accuracy: 0.453125
Step 5000, Minibatch Loss= 1.0196, Training Accuracy= 0.516
-Testing Accuracy: 0.5078125
Testing Accuracy: 0.46875
```

Comment: The only mathematical obstacle to normalizing a feature occurs when all its values are identical, which cannot be the case (for otherwise you wouldn't be including such a feature in the first place).  Could you therefore clarify the meaning of your assertion that "it's hard to normalise all of them to have mean 0 and std 1"?

Comment: I mean I am not sure if it's valid/makes sense to normalise different features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your model, it is an RNN trying to predict a time series of plant heights from time-series of rainfall and of solar exposure.

There is no problem in principle with combing different indicators like these, but finding a good way to normalise them is often difficult.  Ideally you want the variances of all the series *and* the variance of the differences of all the series to be similar.  Even harder, you would also like the distributions of both values and differences not to contain any outliers.

In your example, if you are using daily data then rainfall may well pose problems because most days are zero and if you set variance to 1 the spikes indicating rain will often be large.  You might find a boolean indicator for the presence of rain worked better.

You might also find that smoothing is a helpful part of normalisation.  Plants grow relatively slowly, so applying an EWMA (Exponentially Weighted Moving Average) filter with a time constant of a few days to your data before normalising seems unlikely to be damaging, and it will give the RNN friendlier distributions to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. In fact I have more `time series features` such as `min&max temp`, `day_of_the_week` etc that I want to add to the end of the row. How do you think this could affect the model? Would you think using CNN is a better idea given it doesn't assign weight depending on the previous step like RNN does? It's based on my understanding from this link, im not sure if my understanding is correct https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/11621/83084

Comment: I can't really comment, either approach sounds reasonable and I suggest you experiment to find what works best.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the comment!